# invalid identifier in after insert trigger

Tags: sql, plsql

Later on in the SQL I have this:

```
INSERT INTO s1_contact_person (name_and_address_id, contact_person_id, name, add_by, add_date, change_by, change_date )
SELECT MAX(tblPI.port_id), '1', :new.port_name, 'ANY USER', 'ANY USER', SYSDATE
FROM gtt_possible_port_ids tblPI, s1_contact_person cp
WHERE tblPI.serial_nbr = :new.serial_nbr
GROUP BY tblPI.serial_nbr, :new.port_name, cp.add_by, cp.change_by;
```

I added this part `s1_contact_person cp` so I could reference add_by and change by but get a similar error.

The error message is:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
121/8     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
140/18    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CHANGE_BY": invalid identifier
Errors: check compiler log
```

the s1_contact_person table is:

```
CREATE TABLE s1_contact_person (
    name_and_address_id varchar2(10) not null,
    contact_person_id varchar2(10) not null, 
    name varchar2(50 char) null,
    position_code varchar2(10) null,
    phone_nbr varchar2(32) null,
    phone_ext varchar2(5) null, 
    fax_nbr varchar2(32) null,
    toll_free_phone_nbr varchar2(32) null,
    e_mail varchar2(128) null,
    notes varchar2(250 char) null,
    add_by varchar2(40) DEFAULT user not null,
    add_date date DEFAULT sysdate not null,
    change_by varchar2(40) DEFAULT user not null, 
    change_date date DEFAULT sysdate not null, 
    op_software_interface varchar2(30) null, 
    trader_id varchar2(10) null,
    mobile_phone_nbr varchar2(32) null,
    web_address varchar2(250) null,
    epa_contact_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_epa_contact_flag CHECK (epa_contact_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    payment_advice_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_payment_adv_email_flag CHECK (payment_advice_email_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    purchase_settlement_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_pc_settle_email_flag CHECK (purchase_settlement_email_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    sales_settlement_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_sc_settle_email_flag CHECK (sales_settlement_email_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    sop_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_sop_email_flag CHECK (sop_email_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    ar_interest_invoice_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_ar_int_inv_email_flag CHECK (ar_interest_invoice_email_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    ar_withdraw_notice_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_ar_with_not_email_flag CHECK (ar_withdraw_notice_email_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    inactive_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_inactive_flag CHECK (inactive_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    sop_confirmation_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_sop_confirmation_flag CHECK (sop_confirmation_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    customer_statement_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_cust_stat_email_flag CHECK (customer_statement_email_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    payment_receipt_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_pay_receipt_email_flag CHECK (payment_receipt_email_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    tkt_charges_invoice_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_tkt_chg_inv_email_flag CHECK (tkt_charges_invoice_email_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    pc_contract_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_pc_contract_email_flag CHECK (pc_contract_email_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    sc_contract_email_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_sc_contract_email_flag CHECK (sc_contract_email_flag IN ('Y','N')),
    frontier_contact_flag char(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null CONSTRAINT ckc_cp_frontier_contact_flag CHECK (frontier_contact_flag IN ('Y','N')), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_contact_person PRIMARY KEY (name_and_address_id, 
   contact_person_id) using index tablespace smartsoft_index 
) ORGANIZATION HEAP tablespace smartsoft_data /
```

Comment: You can't just add a table like that without joining it with one of the existing tables and in this case it makes no sense to add a table just to use it in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: BTW, INSERT INTO expects 7 values, and you provided 6 of them.

Comment: Yeah, I know,,typo